# How can I inject OS hostname value in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Is it possible to do something like that?

```
@Value("${xxx.hostname}")
private String hostname;
```

Is it also possible to get any other System Environment Property like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot automatically allow you to take environment variable.

You can just do `@Value("${HOSTNAME}")` (if HOSTNAME is defined ofc)

You can also use your `application.properties` to have something like :

`xxx.hostname = ${HOSTNAME}`

Comment: Thank you sir. Is there a list of these properties I can use directly in spring boot?

Comment: Every environment variables are directly usable. You can check their documentation for more useful information about config management